# Passing property to next method

Tags: php

I have the following code within my class

```
class Mail {
    function AddAttachment($path, $name = '', $filetype = 'application/octet-stream') {
        if (!@is_file($path)){
            echo'<pre>Filepath was not found.</pre>';
        }

        if (empty($name)) {
            echo 'no filename';
        }

        //store attachment in array
        if(!isset($attachments)) {
            $attachments = array();
        }

        $attachments[] = array('path' => $path,'name' => $name,'type' => $filetype);
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($attachment);
        return  $attachments;
    }

    function SetMail() {
        foreach ($this->$attachments as $attachment) {
            echo '<pre>';print_r($attachment);
        }
    }
}

$mail = new Mail;
$mail->AddAttachment('../images/logo.png','filename');
$mail->AddAttachment('../images/logo.png','filensame');
$mail->SetMail();
```

As you can see, i fristly create the array's for the attachments (addAttachment), this works fine. Though I cannot seem to use this array in the next method.

I try'd to make the $attachments property public, but I still get these error messages:

(without public): Cannot access empty property

(with public): Cannot access empty property

(when using `self::$attachments` instead of `$this::$attachments`) :Access to undeclared static property:

Can anybody explain how i can pass the $attachments property to the SetMail method?

Thanks allready!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: You must declare the variable as a "class variable" not as a "method variable", learn first about variable scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to send the `attachments` to the `SetMail` method. It must be done automatically.
You must declare `attachments` variable inside the class. And when you want to access it, you must do it
with `$this->attachments`:

```
<?php

class Mail {
    private $attachments = array();

    function AddAttachment($path, $name = '', $filetype = 'application/octet-stream') {
        $this->attachments[] = array('path' => $path,'name' => $name,'type' => $filetype);
        return  $this->attachments;

    }

    function SetMail()  {
        foreach ($this->attachments as $attachment) {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($attachment);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
}

$mail = new Mail;
$mail->AddAttachment('../images/logo.png','filename1');
$mail->AddAttachment('../images/logo.png','filename2');
$mail->SetMail();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring a new $attachments variable everytime you call AddAttachment

```
class Mail
{
    private $attachments=array();

    function AddAttachment($path, $name = '', $filetype = 'application/octet-stream')
    {
        if (!@is_file($path)){
            echo'<pre>Filepath was not found.</pre>';
        }
        if (empty($name))
        {
            echo 'no filename';
        }
        $att= array('path' => $path,'name' => $name,'type' => $filetype);

        $this->attachments[]=$att;

        return  $att;
    }
    function SetMail() 
    {
        foreach ($this->$attachments as $attachment)
        {
            echo '<pre>';print_r($attachment);
        }
    }
}
```